# Moving certain items to workbooks works for one but not the others

Tags: excel, vba

Basically i need to move certain items to their own workbooks but i am getting a subscript error where it is opening the workbook i need it to go to

```
Sub Team()

    Dim rw As Long, lastrow As Long, MySel As Range 'Grabs skus and moves to new sheet


    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For rw = 1000 To 2 Step -1
            If .Cells(rw, 2).Value Like "*Minor Novice*" And .Cells(rw, 3).Value Like ("*AE*") Then
                If MySel Is Nothing Then
                    Set MySel = .Cells(rw, 1).EntireRow

                        'Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\CODE\Team Lists\11 Minor Novice AE.xlsx"

                        Else
                            Set MySel = Union(MySel, .Cells(rw, 1).EntireRow)

                        End If
                    End If
                Next rw
            End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("M Novice AE")
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If Not MySel Is Nothing Then
            MySel.Copy Destination:=.Cells(lastrow + 1, 1)
            'MySel.Delete
        End If
    End With

    Dim Rng As Range
    Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("M Novice AE").Range("A1:AY300")
    Rng.Copy
    Dim s11 As Workbook
    Set s11 = Workbooks("11 Minor Novice AE")
    Dim last As Long
    Dim Rngnew As Range

With s11.Sheets("Sheet1")
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
        last = .Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    Else
        last = 1
    End If
End With
    Set Rngnew = s11.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & last)

    Rngnew.PasteSpecial





    Dim rw1 As Long, lastrow1 As Long, MySel1 As Range 'Grabs skus and moves to new sheet


    With Workbooks("11 Production").Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For rw1 = 1000 To 2 Step -1
            If .Cells(rw1, 2).Value Like "*Minor Novice*" And .Cells(rw1, 3).Value Like ("*A*") Then
                If MySel1 Is Nothing Then
                    Set MySel1 = .Cells(rw1, 1).EntireRow

                        Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\CODE\Team Lists\11 Minor Novice A.xlsx"

                        Else
                            Set MySel1 = Union(MySel1, .Cells(rw1, 1).EntireRow)

                        End If
                    End If
                Next rw1
            End With

      With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("M Novice A")
        lastrow1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If Not MySel1 Is Nothing Then
            MySel1.Copy Destination:=.Cells(lastrow1 + 1, 1)
            'MySel.Delete
        End If
    End With

    Dim Rng1 As Range
    Set Rng1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("M Novice A").Range("A1:AY300")
    Rng1.Copy
    Dim s111 As Workbook
    Set s111 = Workbooks("11 Minor Novice A.xlsx")
    Dim last1 As Long
    Dim Rngnew1 As Range

    With s111.Sheets("Sheet1")
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
        last1 = .Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    Else
        last1 = 1
    End If
End With
    Set Rngnew1 = s111.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & last)

    Rngnew1.PasteSpecial


End Sub
```

Error:

> Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\CODE\Team Lists\11 Minor Novice A.xlsx"

Comment: Opening a workbook in a loop is not normally needed. Don't you want to open it later, i.e. `Set s111 = Workbooks.Open...`?

Comment: This could probably benefit from some more explanation of what you're trying to do, more detail on your thought process (and fewer random characters to defeat the system's attempt to request that extra explanation).

Comment: *getting a subscript error* - what is the error message? they may help you (and us) diagnose the issue